# Force user to enter login credentials on facebook for auth login even if he has facebook session on browser

Tags: facebook

I am implementing a functionality to login facebook user via auth. For this I am redirecting the user to facebook using following url

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxxxxx&scope=user_about_me,friends_about_mefriends_website,offline_access,email&state=facebookgraph

now if I do not have logged in to facebook in same browser then it works fine. But if I already have session then redirects me back to my site with the code from the same session. I saw some sites that always ask for login credentials (no matter if I have fb session or not).

I found some settings in "Advanced" tab of my fb application saying "Forces use of login secret for auth.login" and I enabled it but still no success. Is there any option to do so?

Thanks

Comment: I got solution from the following links 

[Facebook blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/)

[Facebook login integration on my website](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/facebook-login-integration-website)